# How do i truncate url using python

Tags: python

How  do i truncate the below URL next to the domain "com" using python. i.e you tube.com  only

```
    youtube.com/video/AiL6nL
    yahoo.com/video/Hhj9B2
    youtube.com/video/MpVHQ
    google.com/video/PGuTN
    youtube.com/video/VU34MI
```

Is it possible to truncate like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out Pythons [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) library. It is a standard library so nothing else needs to be installed.

So you could do the following:

```
import urlparse
import re

def check_and_add_http(url):
    # checks if 'http://' is present at the start of the URL and adds it if not.
    http_regex = re.compile(r'^http[s]?://')
    if http_regex.match(url):
        # 'http://' or 'https://' is present
        return url
    else:
        # add 'http://' for urlparse to work.
        return 'http://' + url

for url in url_list:
    url = check_and_add_http(url)
    print(urlparse.urlsplit(url)[1])
```

You can read more about [`urlsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) in the documentation, including the indexes if you want to read the other parts of the URL.

Comment: Does it really work even without scheme part? I get empty strings.

Comment: from urlparse import urlparse
url = urlparse('http://www.youtube.com/video/wpmkqYRfVkk')
print "url = " + str (url)

Comment: @alecxe: indeed, `urlsplit()` doesn't work in this case (because `http://` part is missing in the input): `urlsplit("youtube.com/video/AiL6nL")` -> `SplitResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='youtube.com/video/AiL6nL', query='', fragment='')`

Comment: updated to check for schema and add a `http://` if not present to make parsing easier

Answer (score 4):

You can use split():

```
myUrl.split(r"/")[0]
```

to get "youtube.com"

and:

```
myUrl.split(r"/", 1)[1]
```

to get everything else

Comment: you could use `.partition('/')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the function [`urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) from the standard library:

```
from urlparse import urlsplit # python 2
from urllib.parse import urlsplit # python 3

myurl = "http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html"
urlsplit(myurl)[1] # returns 'docs.python.org'
```

Answer (score 0):

No library function can tell that those strings are supposed to be absolute URLs, since, formally, they are relative ones. So, you have to prepend `//`.

```
>>> url = 'youtube.com/bla/foo'
>>> urlparse.urlsplit('//' + url)[1]
                 > 'youtube.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a crazy alternative solution using [tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract):

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> ext = tldextract.extract('youtube.com/video/AiL6nL')
>>> ".".join(ext[1:3])
'youtube.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular input, you could use [`str.partition()` or `str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
print('youtube.com/video/AiL6nL'.partition('/')[0])
# -> youtube.com
```

Note: `urlparse` module (that you could use in general to parse an url) doesn't work in this case:

```
import urlparse

urlparse.urlsplit('youtube.com/video/AiL6nL')
# -> SplitResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='youtube.com/video/AiL6nL',
#                query='', fragment='')
```

In general, it is safe to use a regex here if you know that all lines start with a hostname  and otherwise each line contains [a well-formed uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B):

```
import re

print("\n".join(re.findall(r"(?m)^\s*([^\/?#]*)", text)))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/yPkK23)

```
youtube.com
yahoo.com
youtube.com
google.com
youtube.com
```

Note: it doesn't remove the optional port part -- `host:port`.